# Kendo React SharePoint Peoplepicker

Tags: sharepoint, peoplepicker, kendo-react-ui

Is there a PeoplePicker in Kendo React
or can I combine PnP PeoplePicker https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/PeoplePicker/#implementation

with Kendo React Input component?

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't think it can be done.
I recommand you to ask this question in pnp controller [github](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/issues).